# how to enable and disable button when doing validation of textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, html

```js
var fname;
var fpan;
var sname;
var span;
var tname;
var tpan;

$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
});

function validate() {
  $('#fpan').on("blur", function() {

    fpan = $("#fpan").val();

    if (fpan.length == 10) {

      $("#pan-valid").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-invalid").addClass("hidden");
      return true;
    } else {

      $("#pan-invalid").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-valid").addClass("hidden");

      return false;
    }

  });

  $('#span').on("blur", function() {

    span = $("#span").val();


    if (span.length == 10) {

      $("#pan-valid2").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-invalid2").addClass("hidden");
      return true;
    } else {

      $("#pan-user-invalid2").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-user-valid2").addClass("hidden");

      return false;
    }

  });

  $('#tpan').on("blur", function() {

    tpan = $("#tpan").val();


    if (tpan.length == 10) {

      $("#pan-valid3").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-invalid3").addClass("hidden");
      return true;
    } else {

      $("#pan-invalid3").addClass("hidden").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pan-valid3").addClass("hidden");

      return false;
    }

  });

  if (fhn == "") {
    $("#generate").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  //        else{
  //            $("#generate").attr("disabled", false);
  //        }
  else if (fhn != "" && fpan != "") {
    $("#generate").attr("disabled", false);
  } else if (shn == "") {
    $("#generate").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label> First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label>first pan:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fpan" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label> First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label>first pan:</label>
    <input type="text" id="span" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label> First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tname" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label>first pan:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tpan" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">
  </form>
```

I am using attr(disabled ) to enable and disable button of form when textbox is empty and filled by using validate function.but when I am using this so it get disable and when I fill data into tfisrtname and fpan so it is not able to enable. basically what I want to do is as below:
If firstname text1 is blank than disable button and if text1 and pan1 is filled than enable button.
If If sname text2 is blank than disable button and if (text1 and pan1) &(text2 and pan2) are filled than enable button.
And if If If tname text3 is blank than disable button and if (text1 and pan1) &(text2 and pan2)  & (text3 and pan3)are filled than enable button.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to things: 
To disable:
`$(selector).attr('disabled', 'disabled')`

To enable:
`$(selector).removeAttr('disabled')`

You just need bunch of if else statements to use those statements.

Comment: I used this thing But Idont know why only it disabled my button but not enabling it

Answer (score 0):

The code for your condition should be like that:

```
if(
   ($('#fname').val() != "" && $('#fpan').val() != "") ||
   ($('#sname').val() != "" && $('#span').val() != "") ||
   ($('#tname').val() != "" && $('#tpan').val() != "")
  )
{
    //enable
    $('#Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else
{
    //disable
    $('#Submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: thanks @Michael ,but this is working little bit when fname and fpan are filled than enabled else disabled ,but what I want here as I mentioned above that fanme && fpan filled  when both are filled than only sname and span are if filled than it should be enble button if fname and fpan are blank and  if you are trying to fill sname and span than it should disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-using most of your code.  I have minimized some of it.

See if this helps you.  You might need to add the checking of content length (if that's necessary - I took it out as I am not sure how much of a requirement this is)

**See demo below**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isValid;

  // start with disabled button
  $("#Submit").prop('disabled', true);

  $("input[type='text'").on('change', function() {
    isValid = validateFields();

    if (isValid) {
      $("#Submit").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#Submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  var validateFields = function() {
    var span = $("#span").val();
    var fpan = $("#fpan").val();
    var tpan = $("#tpan").val();
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var sname = $("#sname").val();
    var tname = $("#tname").val();

    if (sname.length > 0 && span.length > 0 &&
      fname.length > 0 && fpan.length > 0 &&
      tname.length > 0 && tpan.length > 0) {

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fpan" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="span" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tpan" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: because of $("input[type='text']") ,I am not able to enable or disable because when I enter value into text of fname so it immediately started checking this condition and not able to get value of fname and all

Comment: I am getting value on blur function of each text and this one is not working not able to disable button

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleDisabled(target) {
  var $target = $(target);
  console.log($target.val().length > 0)
  console.log($target.attr("id"))
  $("input:button").prop('disabled', !$target.val());
}

var $notnull = $('form input:not(:button)');
$notnull.each(function(i, el) {
  toggleDisabled(el);
});
$notnull.on('input', function(e) {
  toggleDisabled(e.currentTarget);
  $notnull.each(function(i, el) {
    toggleDisabled(el);
  });
}).trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fpan" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="span" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label> First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tname" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <label>first pan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tpan" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

1. It checks every input if there are empty then disable
2. It also check on input on text